# How to skip update to Windows 11 on Windows insider program?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-insider, windows-11

I am on Windows 10 (Home Edition) and want to try out [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg) but don't want to upgrade to Windows 11. Switching to insider Dev and Beta channels start downloading Windows 11.

[image: Windows 10 Insider Settings Channel Selection]

How do I get the Windows 10 build 21364 (https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/04/21/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-21364/) without installing Windows 11 first?

Comment: I think you would have to download the specific ISO file and run that to install it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am on Windows 10 (Home Edition) and want to try out WSLg but don't want to upgrade to Windows 11.

According to a lead Microsoft OS engineer, there are no plans to support WSLg on Windows 10, build 21364 ultimately became Windows 11.

> WSLg will ships with Windows 11. At this time there are no plan to enable WSLg in Windows 10.

Source: [shipping with windows 10 21H2 or Windows 11](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/446)

Microsoft has actually updated their WSL documentation on this particular subject.  So in this particular case, the blog article, contains out of date information.

> You will need to be on Windows 11 Build 22000 or higher to access this feature. You can join the Windows Insiders Program to get the latest preview builds.

Source: [Install support for Linux GUI apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps#install-support-for-linux-gui-apps)

Windows 10 Insider Preview build 21364 is due to expire on October 31, 2021.  While it is still possible to download an ISO for that specific build from a website like [uupdump.net](https://uupdump.net/) by searching for that particular build. You would then only have two choices, upgrade to Windows 11 Insider Preview Developer channel build or perform a clean install of Windows 10 version 21H2.

I would point out that running build 21364 would only solve one problem, you would still have to update the vGPU driver which likely no longer supports build 21364.

It's worth pointing out that all the eligible Windows 10 Insider Preview builds from the Developer channel are due to expire on the same date.  Unless Microsoft backports WSLg to Windows 10 at a later date, like they eventually did with WSL2 and earlier builds, the only way to get WSLg is to upgrade to Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a virtual machine and install in it
the Windows Insider version.

You can download these versions in ISO format from the page
[Windows Insider Preview Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso).

You will need a version that is an Insider Preview build version 21362
or later to support WSLg.
The latest version should be the most stable.